# Start bc with pi defined

Tags: alias, bc, math

I would like to create an alias for `bc` that runs `bc -l` and specifies that `pi=4*a(1)`. This way, I can start each session with pi already defined. What alias will do this?

Comment: Welcome to Unix.stackexchange! I recommend you [take the tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22621753/5207302

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will answer your Question, but you should consider following the link provided by Julie Pelletier

assuming you are using bash:

> alias bc-l-with-pi='bc -l <(echo "pi=4*a(1)")'

explanation:

we (ab)use the bash redirection to give bc a temporary file with the content "pi=4*a(1)". after that bc goes into interactive mode.